# Darktable 2.4.4 exiv2 0.2.6 lensfun issues

Tags: linux-mint

I am trying to get Darktable 2.4.4 to use exiv2 0.2.6 in Darktable to match up my Lens. I'm using Darktable 2.4.4 on Linux Mint 19 Xfce. I have updated Lensfun (v0.3.2.4) The problem is: My Nikon D5300 is recognized, no problem, but the kit lens (Nikon AF-P DX Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G VR) shows in the "image module" on the right hand side as lens "160" instead of the lens name.
I have to manually select the lens in the lens correction module every time (it is listed, so it's there). The lens is listed as '160' and says, "Camera/lens not found-please select manually" (which you can). This can be tedious. I'm positive this lens (Nikon AF-P DX Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G VR) worked automatically with Darktable in an earlier version.
I have searched hi and low for an answer or fix, i even tried to install darktable from source but failed, if anyone can help me or steer me in the right direction i would be greatly appreciative.